# How much time invalidate() takes for calling onDraw method of a view

Tags: android, performance, view, android-canvas, invalidation

Maybe for most applications this doesn't stands an issue, but, what if I want to redraw a view and my particular app requires a high resolution?.What I'm trying to say here is that you can have a situation where with the slightest change of ***any input***(for example a touch event) you want to redraw a view, then most probable you will lose some of these changes on the input because of the time that invalidate() takes for calling onDraw method of the view. I'm pretty sure that this is an *always present trouble* due more to hardware capabilities than software, so, my questions are:

1. Am I right?
2. If this is the case, then can you possibly know how much error will this introduce on these particular *high resolution apps*

Comment: yes it does depend on the hardware capabilities of the device. What do you mean by error? you might run it memory leaks is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: No, I just meant for something like a rate: detected_inputs/total_inputs

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what are you looking for, but I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269236/delay-in-calling-ondraw) question while looking for [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421233/invalidate-not-calling-ondraw-after-some-activity-finish) about `invalidate()` not working and @Rachiet said the delay between `invalidate()` and `onDraw()` is something like 100 ms.