# Delay in calling onDraw()

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I am writing a code which requires to update a UI multiple times within a second to display an animation .But after calling invalidate the onDraw() method gets called after around 100ms and hence the number of times the screen is repainted is reduced to only 4 or 5 times a second.

I want to know as to what exactly causes the time difference between the invalidate() command and the calling of onDraw method.

Is there any way I can reduce the delay so that my animation can be smooth??
Thanks in advance.

It is a big code I'll just post the simple format for it:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    private boolean doDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        <Loop>
        tuneMatrix(matrix);//here i am changing the values for the matrix.(ie scaling and all)
        invalidate();
        System.out.println("CustomImageView.doDoubleTap():invalidate");
        </LOOP>
    }

    onDraw(){
        System.out.println("CustomImageView.onDraw():start");
        //my code changes
    }
}
```

Now the timedifference between logs 
"CustomImageView.doDoubleTap():invalidate" and "CustomImageView.onDraw():start" is ~100ms.
I want to reduce that to a max of 30ms.

Comment: try to start any std animarion on your view e.g. ScaleAnimation and see how often onDraw is called, i think 5 fps is a typical value

Comment: Sorry, hadn't had my coffee before. Can we see some code? 50 or 60fps should be within your reach.

Comment: please check.. i have updated the code

Comment: What do the loop tags mean?

Comment: its just a for loop to loop the enclosed code a specified no of times. In my code I had this to loop my code for a number of times for a time limit of 300ms . It loops for only 2 or 3 times max whereas i want it for at least 7 times to present a smooth animation.Every thing is working fine ,I just cannot decrease the difference between my calling of invalidate and the when the onDraw() is being called internally.

Comment: And is doDoubleTap running on the main thread or a background thread?